# Нету возможности переключения configs через консоль wg setconf [<args>]

Tags: bash, vpn

Проблема в том что не могу использую команду: wg setconf <название интерфейса> <файл конфига>

Вот такая ошибка:

```
C:\Users>wg setconf 1685564 1685564.conf
Line unrecognized: `Address=10.22.163.6'
Configuration parsing error
```

С чем может быть проблема? Вот структура самого конфига:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.22.163.6/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = CCrCmBhHRuqPmMkH/aE1jlEWKkh4NsK8A5KoeuWhqnY=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = de2.wg.finevpn.org:993
PersistentKeepalive = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет имени `Address` в секции `[Interface]`:

> CONFIGURATION FILE FORMAT
>
> The configuration file format is based on INI. There are two top level sections -- Interface and Peer. Multiple Peer sections
> may be specified,  but only one Interface section may be specified.
>
> The Interface section may contain the following fields:
>
> - PrivateKey — a base64 private key generated by wg genkey. Required.
> - ListenPort — a 16-bit port for listening. Optional; if not specified, chosen randomly.
> - FwMark  —  a 32-bit fwmark for outgoing packets. If set to 0 or "off", this option is disabled. May be specified in
>   hexadecimal by prepending
>   "0x". Optional.